# threejs colorsNeedUpdate not triggering update

Tags: javascript, three.js

I am trying to trigger a change of face color on external event - button. Even though there are many similar questions, none of the offered solutions worked out so far. So, I have an interactive model and  I want to be able to toggle its colors.

The model is rendered and colored on `init()` (ignore the fact it is being colored in for loop, there are some coloring conditions going on, which are irrelevant here)

First I iterate through faces and color them

```
geometry = new THREE.Geometry().fromBufferGeometry( object );
var faceIndices = [ 'a', 'b', 'c' ];
for ( var i = 0; i < geometry.faces.length; i ++ ) {
    var face  = geometry.faces[ i ];
    for( var j = 0; j < 3; j++ ) {
        color = new THREE.Color( 0xff0000 );
        face.vertexColors[ j ] = color;
    }
}
```

Then I set the material and its flags

```
var material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial( { color: 0xffffff, vertexColors: THREE.FaceColors} );
material.needsUpdate = true;
var solidModel = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
solidModel.dynamic = true;
solidModel.name = "solid";
```

After which I add it to the scene which is being rendered

```
scene.add( solidModel );
```

And that works fine. Here comes the troubling part. On click I call the `color()` function

```
console.log("Coloring...");
// Color the object
var solid = scene.getObjectByName("solid"); // retrieve the object from the scene
// change colors
for ( var i = 0; i < solid.geometry.faces.length; i ++ ) {
    var face  = solid.geometry.faces[ i ];
    for( var j = 0; j < 3; j++ ) {
        color = new THREE.Color(  0xffffff );
        color.setHex( Math.random() * 0xffffff );
        face.vertexColors[ j ] = color;
    }
}
// raise the update flag
solid.geometry.colorsNeedUpdate = true;
```

And nothing happens.
I also tried by removing the solid object from the scene, creating the new one frome the same geometry and again adding it to the scene. Also doesn't work.

What is really curious is that within the chrome debugger, `colorsNeedUpdate` flag on the "solid" object is actually `true` at the rendering time.

I work with threejs r84

Any insight would be helpful

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < solid.geometry.faces.length; i++) {
  var face = solid.geometry.faces[i];
  for (var j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
    face.vertexColors[j].setHex(Math.random() * 0xffffff);
  }
}
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/prisoner849/0Lnhknc4/) example

Comment: It works! Can you please explain how is it different and if I should change it in the main loop as well? Thank you!

Comment: it's better not to use a new `THREE.Color()`, but change the existing one.

Comment: ok, thanx! How so that the `new THREE.Color()` approach didn't work?

Comment: I just follow [WestLangley's advice](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43130791/4045502) :)

Comment: I see! Thank you! :)