# Only geometry.elementsNeedUpdate results in memory allocation - why?

Tags: javascript, memory, three.js

If I have a simple animate function

```
function animate() {
geometry.elementsNeedUpdate = true;  // allocates memory without geometry.faces[ 0 ].color = ...    
requestAnimationFrame( animate );
renderer.render( scene, camera ); }
```

I get a memory allocation, even if no element is changed.
Then I add the manipulation of the color of the face.

```
function animate() {

geometry.elementsNeedUpdate = true;  
// geometry.colorsNeedUpdate = true; // not necessary
// material.needsUpdate = true;      // not necessary
time = clock.getElapsedTime();  
if ( time * 16 % 10 < 5 ) { 
    geometry.faces[ 0 ].color = colorBlue;      
} else {    
    geometry.faces[ 0 ].color = colorRed;       
}
requestAnimationFrame( animate );
renderer.render( scene, camera ); }
```

and it remains in the memory allocation.

`geometry.elementsNeedUpdate = true;` is necessary to change the face colors.

How to avoid memory allocation?

The full example is available at http://sandbox.threejs.hofk.de/memory/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to change the face colors of your object.

You can do so using `copy()` or `setHex()` like so:

```
mesh.geometry.faces[ 0 ].color.copy( myColor ); // or .setHex( 0xff0000 )

mesh.geometry.colorsNeedUpdate = true; // required if geometry previously rendered
```

Do not set other `needsUpdate` flags unnecessarily.

Do not *assign* a new `THREE.Color` object, as you are currently doing.

three.js r.84