# three.js Memory Leak when using `elementsNeedUpdate`

Tags: javascript, memory-leaks, three.js

I am creating a `Geometry` in three.js and populating it with vertices to build a 2D terrain. I am pushing all of the `Vector3`s and `Face3`s to the geometry as soon as my terrain is created, and then modifying each vertex and face every frame.

Because I am modifying the face vertices every frame, I need to tell three.js to update the faces. I am doing this using `geometry.elementsNeedUpdate = true`. This works, however I have noticed it causes a substantially large amount of memory usage (my app uses an extra ~50mb of RAM *every second*).

The following code demonstrates what I'm trying to do:

```
function pushEverything(geom) {
    for (var i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
        geom.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(...));
        geom.faces.push(new THREE.Face3(...));
        geom.faces.push(new THREE.Face3(...));
    }
}

function rebuild(geom) {
    for (var face of geom.faces) {
        face.a = ...
        face.b = ...
        face.c = ...
    }
    geom.elementsNeedUpdate = true
}

var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
        canvas: document.getElementById("my-canvas")
});
var geom = new THREE.Geometry();
var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(...);
pushEverything(geom);
while (true) {
    // Perform some terrain modifications
    rebuild(geom);
    renderer.render(geom, camera);
    sleep(1000 / 30);
}
```

I have already followed the advice of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43126199/only-geometry-elementsneedupdate-results-in-memory-allocation-why) question, which suggested using `geometry.vertices[x].copy(...)` instead of `geometry.vertices[x] = new Vector3(...)`.

My question is: why is my memory usage so high when using `geometry.elementsNeedUpdate = true`? Is there an alternative method to updating a `Geometry`'s faces?

I am using three.js 0.87.1 from NPM.

Comment: Which version do you use? https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/9353

Comment: I have updated my question. I am using three.js 0.87.1 downloaded from NPM.

Comment: Can you provide some info about the timing: When is `rebuild` called? and `pushEverything`? When is the scene being rendered? What is this `sleep` function?

Comment: @neeh `rebuild` is called every frame. `pushEverything` is pushed before the first render. `sleep` is just a conventional 'sleep' (suspend the thread of execution for `1000 / 30` milliseconds). I have updated my question to show where I am rendering.

Comment: Internally, Three.js deals with `BufferGeometry`, it cannot use `Geometry`. `elementsNeedUpdate` means "my `Geometry` is updated and needs to be converted to a `BufferGeometry`". Converting from `Geometry` to `BufferGeometry` is a heavy operation both in memory, CPU and GPU (the `Geometry` is first converted to a `DirectGeometry` before it can be converted to a `BufferGeometry`).

If you can explain more precisely what you're trying to achieve, we'll probably be able to find a solution

Comment: And I forgot to add: the fact `rebuild` is called every frame should be problem here, because of what I said above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found and solved the issue. It was not a memory leak on three.js' part, but it was a memory leak on my part.

I was creating a `Geometry` and allowing myself to clone it, perform modifications to the clone, and then merge it back into the original. What I didn't realise is that I should call `geometry.dispose()` on the cloned geometry when I was done with it. So, I was basically cloning the geometry every frame, which explains the huge memory usage.

I have fixed my issue by converting the `Geometry` to a `BufferGeometry`, and calling `geometry.dispose()` on the geometry when I am done with it. I now have expected memory usage.